# The windows script adding the appropriate characters to .txt

Tags: sql, windows, delphi, cmd, windows-scripting

I would like to create a script that will be turned sql command of the form which can be assigned to a string in Delphi. Example (text in .txt file):

```
select name,species,quantity from lamas
where species='Alpaca'
and name='Andrew'
```

I want :

```
  'select name,species from lamas '+
  'where species='Alpaca' '+
  'and name='Andrew' ';
```

At the beginning of each line txt file I would add `'`
On end of line `'+'`
And on end file instead `'+'` simple `';`.

Comment: Where is the Sql coming from?  If you have it in, say, aTMemo, it is easy to generate the text you want and copy it to the clipboard so that you can paste it into code.

Comment: What have you tried? It seems that a simple `for` loop over `TFile.ReadAllLines` with `QuotedStr` and some string concatenation would do the trick. So what's your actual problem here?

Comment: Also what do you need a script for? You can just write a Delphi app, but of course it would be possible to do that in any scripting language as well (JScript, VBScript, Python, Lua, you name it ...).

Comment: You are correct , it will use the makings of a simple program in any language , we need not itself hinders

Comment: Get Notepad++ and learn regex.  Do a find/replace to switch `'` into `"`, then find `^(.*)$`, replace with `'(\1) ' +`, type one semicolon for the last line.  Better yet, get away from concatenation and use the `.SQL` property as a `TStrings` and instead replace with`LQuery.SQL.Add\('(\1)'\);`

Comment: as @J... suggested your favourite text editor will do this.  If you don't have a favourite text editor get one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Windows CMD script:

```
@echo OFF
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set j="@@@@@"
for /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%i in ('type %1') do (

  IF  NOT !j!== "@@@@@" (
   echo '!j!'+ >>output.txt   
  )

  set j=%%i
  set j=!j:'=''!
)
echo '!j!'; >>output.txt
```

If you call it with your .txt file parameter

```
script.cmd example.txt
```

You'll get `output.txt` file:

```
'select name,species,quantity from lamas'+    
'where species=''Alpaca'''+    
'and name=''Andrew''';
```

Note: in Delphi you should also change single quotas around strings ('Alpaca','Andrew') in the SQL command with double quotas. This script implements this.

Comment: Really nice script! But I have an issue running it: After running the script, output.txt just contains the filename of the input file.

Comment: @RenéHoffmann  It seems that the file name contains spaces. I've changed the script to handle this. In the "FOR " line change `%1` to `'type %1'`

Comment: How to look like a script that would have to convert the other way around?